# Is it possible to edit and move images using PHP?

Tags: php, image

I'm looking to edit and move an image using PHP.

For example, I want to transform this image:

> http://zanterite.club/before.png

And turn it into this image:

> http://zanterite.club/after.png

I don't exactly need a code written for it, just pointed in the general direction if possible. How would I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes........ Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Hello Pete, first off, I would definitely follow Bonatti's advice and get a bit more knowledge on asking questions so that we can better help you. Many PHP 3rd party libraries exist which can help you achieve what you are looking to do. One of the most popular image manipulation libraries for PHP  i've used before is intervention. Here is their site / docs: http://image.intervention.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter to get you going, you will probably need something along the lines of:

```
# Create a new canvas big enough for result
$im=imagecreatetruecolor(x,y);

# Fill canvas with pukey yellow colour background
$yellowbkgrnd=imagecolorallocate($im,255,247,212);
imagefill($im,0,0,$yellowbkgrnd);

# Load basic, original rainbow image
$orig=imagecreatefrompng("original.png");

# Copy basic original image across top of new one
imagecopyresampled($im,$orig,...);

# Now paste it again, but smaller and further down, left aligned
imagecopyresampled($im,$orig,...);

# And paste one last time, to the right of previous pasted copy
imagecopyresampled($im,$orig,...);

 # Save result to file
imagepng($im,"result.png");
```

[Reference documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)